# JScrollPane and jPlayer with playlist

Tags: jscrollpane, jplayer, playlist

I'm trying to implement jScrollPane on a playlist generated by jPlayer (with playlist) but it's not working. I think what is happening is that jPlayer builds the playlist dynamically after jScrollPane has been initialized on the playlist ul element.

The jPlayer and jPlayerPlaylist work fine; and I can see the element css added by jScrollPane, which shows it’s working, but the scrollbars are not visible. Possibly I'd need to call jScrollPane after the playlist has finished building? Does anybody have experience with these plugins?

Thanks!
The site is here: http://elricoshow.com

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, after a few tries… I think it was something with the css, maybe because I was trying to have a non-javascript version too, I'm not sure.

Anyways, I've managed to make some very nice scroll bars that blend well with the page, and that work better on a touchscreen (or with the mousewheel) than say a Carousel (because with the carousel you need to click for every advance).